# Wordpress developer retrive permalink to textbox

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When I create a new page in WordPress, the permalink will auto-generated and I wishes the same permalink will imitate into the textbox, as per image attached, currently, the textbox is retrieving the URL by `get_the_permalink($_REQUEST['post'])`, is there any way I can get the same with the one auto-generated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may use the `get_sample_permalink()` function as [found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sample_permalink/). Try:

```
get_sample_permalink( $_REQUEST['post'] );
```

Comment: it causes a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_sample_permalink()

Comment: In which case I'd take a look at post.php to try and reverse-engineer https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/post.php